# Generate 2 vectors using ranges-v3

Tags: c++, range-v3

I have two vectors, of different types, lets say int and double. I also have a third vector with indices and I want to extract the values of the two first vectors corresponding to the indices with range-v3.

Right now I have this

```
std::vector<int> A {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
std::vector<double> B{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
std::vector<int> indices{0,2,3};

const std::vector<int> A_slice = indices | 
    ranges::views::transform([](const auto i) {return 2*i;}) | 
    ranges::views::transform([&A](const auto i) {return A[i]}) |
    ranges::to_vector;

const std::vector<double> B_slice = indices | 
    ranges::views::transform([](const auto i) {return 2*i;}) | 
    ranges::views::transform([&B](const auto i) {return B[i]}) | 
    ranges::to_vector;
```

This is not the most efficient way, as you need to iterate twice and do the `2*i` transform twice.
One solution would be to get a vector of pairs

```
const auto AB_slice = indices | 
    ranges::views::transform([](const auto i) {return 2*i;}) | 
    ranges::views::transform([&A, &B](const auto i) {return std::make_pair(A[i], B[i]);}) |
    ranges::to_vector;
```

but this is different from two separate vectors.
Is there a way to obtain two separate vectors?

Comment: I have no idea about the `ranges` thing but did you think about storing the result of first transform and reusing it for both A and B?

Comment: ranges are lazy. They are only evaluated while you iterate, in this case, during the to_vector. This has the benefit that you dont need to store it. But apparently, it has the drawback that you have to iterate twice...

Comment: A normal loop will be shorter, clearer and run and compile faster :-)

Comment: For this particular case, of course. But this is a demo example to ask if ranges can do something in particular.

Comment: @jjcasmar, so all in all you're looking for an `unzip` function.

Answer (score 1):

So accumulate them yourself, if you want to:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>
int main() {
    std::vector<int> A {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<double> B{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    std::vector<int> indices{0,2,3};

    const auto AB_slice = ranges::accumulate(
        indices | ranges::views::transform([](const auto i) {return 2*i;}),
        std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>(),
        [&](std::pair<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>> v, int i) { 
            v.first.push_back(A[i]);
            v.second.push_back(B[i]);
            return std::move(v);
        }
    );

    for (auto i : AB_slice.first) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
    for (auto i : AB_slice.second) {
        std::cout << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: this is pretty interesting. I would have never thought about ranges this way!

Comment: Isn't the `std::move` redundant, considering that `v` is a copy?